# Can subclasses (not using inheritance) have it's creator reference?

Tags: python, class, oop

I don't know how to exactly write a title for this, so let me explain my problem. I'm using Python 3 to implement a bot on Slack, but my doubt is about how classes can be used to solve it.

I'm using [Slack's API](https://api.slack.com/methods) to create a bot to send messages. When you use the API to send a message, it returns some parameters that indentifies this message (like an id). With this "id" I can change the message's text or delete it, for example.

I created a main class that will be used to handle the API requests and therefore, send messages. I also have another class called SlackMessage that keeps the message's "id" and will have some methods, like change it's text or delete itself, for example. So, when I send a message through the main class, an instance of SlackMessage class will be returned.

As the first class is handling the requests to the API, the SlackMessage class should use it when changing it's text. Would be right the SlackMessage class have the main class as reference when it's being created and use it to update itself?

Here's some code to explain what I mean:

```
class Slack:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self._token = token

    def send_message(self, message):
        result = requests.post(...)

        #Get message's reference
        ts = result["ts"]
        channel = result["channel"]
        text = result["text"]

        reference = {"ts": ts, "channel": channel, "text": text}

        return SlackMessage(self, reference)

    def update_message(self, message_reference):
        result = requests.post(...)

    class SlackMessage:
        def __init__(self, slack_client, reference):
            self._slack_client = slack_client
            self._reference = reference

        def change_text(self, text):
            self._reference["text"] = text
            self._slack_client.update_message(self._reference)
```

And how would be the best method to create a way to delete the message? Should I do it the same way?

Sorry if this question is a duplicate, I searched for an answer but didn't know how to explain the problem with a few words.

Comment: Any particular reason why `SlackMessage` is defined inside `Slack`?

Comment: No, actually I changed it in the file and forgot to change here too